# Changing the navigation drawer to tabs instead

Tags: tabs

I've been working on a simple messaging app which uses a navigation drawer interface consisting of Home, Contacts,Settings,New Group and My Profile.The main content of the screen is one's chats.The app works just fine.I've however thought of using Tabs rather instead of the nav drawer.How can I go about doing this? I've done all my research but none has been of help so far.I want to have three tabs : Home,Contacts and Chats tabs,and the settings icon to contain New Group & My Profile.This is more or less similar to Whatsapp layout.Please guys,I need your help.Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to have some details on the platform you are using. Web, native, Windows, Mac, technologies used, frameworks used, etc.

Comment: Hi Jan_V,Am coding on Android studio 2.3.Am using  windows 8.1